# How to fix error in python code, which will not run over large numbers?

Tags: python, recursion, segmentation-fault

I have written a recursive Python program which I have attached below, which prints out the palindromic primes in an interval. I cannot use loops.

palindromic_primes.py:

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(30000)

# this function places all the numbers between the start and end points into
# a list and determines whether they are prime numbers by seeing if they have
# a remainder of 0 when divided, else numbers that dont have remainder of zero
# are stored.
def check_prime(num_list, number):
    if num_list == []:
        print(number)
    else:
        num = num_list[0]
        if number % num == 0:
            pass
        else:
            num_list.pop(0)
            check_prime(num_list, number)

# this checks whether the numbers in the interval are palindromes by comparing
# the first 'letter' to the last 'letter' for each number and seeing whether
# they match.
def check_palindrome(nums):
    nums1 = nums[::-1]
    if nums1 == nums:
        new_list = list(range(2, int(nums)))
        check_prime(new_list, int(nums))

# this takes both functions and only stores the numbers that match in both
# functions.
def check_done(lists):
    # takes numbers not stored (so the numbers that are palindromes and primes)
    if lists != []:
        check_palindrome(str(lists[0]))
        lists.pop(0)
        check_done(lists)

start_int = int(sys.argv[1])
ending_int = int(sys.argv[2])

palindromic_primes = print("The palindromic primes are:") 
# the list will analyse all numbers from the start point till the end point
list1 = list(range(start_int, ending_int+1))
check_done(list1)
```

I have an error that I am not sure how to fix as the code works fine until I enter an input such as starting point 10000 and ending point 20000, as it gives me a segmentation fault.

when entered to wing IDE, this is what given back [evaluate palindromeprimes.py] Enter the starting point N:  10000 Enter the ending point M:  20000 The palindromic primes are:aborted (disconnected). when I enter it into my school marking system I get this: Your program produced: Enter the starting point N:  Enter the ending point M:  Segmentation fault  Input supplied to your program: 10000 20000   Differences in the files are as follows: 1,29c1,3

Apparently, i need to make my code more efficient, but I'm not sure how to go about this. I saw told to think of the properties of prime numbers and factors, such as the fact that prime numbers are all odd. Factors occur in pairs, so if the number has no factors before some 'midpoint' then it wont have any after that 'midpoint' either

Comment: @AKX This is obviously a special assignment, it is safe to presume loops are simply forbidden, it is a challenge.

Comment: So that segfault usually means your C-Stack running the python application has segfaulted/run out of memory. Have you tried increasing your recursion limit even further in order to avoid this?

Comment: Can you get anything out of Python after the 'Segmentation fault' line? Just to make sure that Python interpreter itself didn't crash.

Comment: @marsolmos when entered to wing IDE, this is what given back [evaluate palindromeprimes.py]
`Enter the starting point N: 
10000
Enter the ending point M: 
20000
The palindromic primes are:aborted (disconnected)`. when I enter it into my school marking system I get this: `Your program produced:
Enter the starting point N: 
Enter the ending point M: 
Segmentation fault

Input supplied to your program:
10000
20000


Differences in the files are as follows:
1,29c1,3`

Comment: Apparently, i need to make my code more efficient, but I'm not sure how to go about this. I saw told to think of the properties of prime numbers and factors, such as the fact that prime numbers are all odd. Factors occur in pairs, so if the number has no factors before some 'midpoint' then it wont have any after that 'midpoint' either

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is one of computational efficiency then it's not necessarily a Python question

These facts should help to reduce the recursion depth:

1. There are many more palindromic numbers than primes - therefore check
   your number is a prime BEFORE you check it's a palindrome
2. To check a number is not a prime you only need to check that the
   modulus is zero when you divide by number up to (and including) the square root of the candidate
3. You only need to check that the number modulus is zero when you
   divide by prime numbers (if it's divisible by 9, 15, 21 ...,  it is divisible by 3)